# github history taking too long to generate

Tags: git, github

Subsequent to a failed install of postgis

```
CREATE EXTENSION PostGIS WITH SCHEMA postgis;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.5/9.5.12/share/postgresql@9.5/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

searching for an appropriate version for a Mavericks set-up with psql 9.5.12 on this page:

```
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commits/master/Formula/postgis.rb
```

is returning

```
Sorry, this commit history is taking too long to generate.
Refresh the page to try again, or view this history locally using the following command:
git log master -- Formula/postgis.rb
```

but that returns `fatal: bad revision 'master'`

Is there another way to query the history  (or to call the postgis based on its dependency on the postgresql version) ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to first clone the repository in order to query its history:

```
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core.git && cd homebrew-core
git log master -- Formula/postgis.rb
```

Alternatively, if you already have Homebrew on your computer, you can directly go in its repository, which you can get with the command `brew tap-info homebrew/core`.

On my Mac this is in `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core`, which is its default location:

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core
git log master -- Formula/postgis.rb
```

Comment: the latter approach I had tried before and now still only got the prompt back as a response... the former loads 235 MB directory and yes a history.  Pity, as I was expecting info on supported OS X installations, but that is not in the stream of releases...

Comment: Re the latter approach you may have a shallow (= incomplete) repository. Run `git fetch --unshallow` to get the full history, then run the `git log` command again.

Comment: When I try the later approach, I get an error message `--unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense`. Yet when I run `git log master -- Formula/postgis.rb` I just get the prompt back... hmm.

Comment: @Adam I just fixed my answer: the previous command was searching for the formula in Homebrew’s main repo rather than in the formulas one.